# Assign variable to attribute in struct

Tags: c, struct, structure

I am having trouble printing the attribute of a c struct. The struct has an integer attribute called room_id and all I am trying to do is print the attribute.

```
static void process_a_reading(struct reading_t reading) {
        int r_id = reading.room_id;
        printf("Room Id: %d", r_id);
}


struct reading_t {
    int room_id ;
    struct event_t event ;
} ;
```

Comment: And when you tried this, the result was…? (Is the `*` really there?)

Comment: How is `process_a_reading()` called? Which parameter for `reading` is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reading_t is the conventional nomenclature used when you make a typedef.  I've modified the example to show a typedef, and replaced the function signature to use the typedef'd type. Also, I would personally pass the struct to the function as a pointer.

```
typedef struct reading {
    int room_id ;
    struct event_t event ;
} reading_t;

static void 
process_a_reading(reading_t *reading) {
    int r_id = reading->room_id;
    printf("Room Id: %d", r_id);
}

int 
main(void) {
      reading_t myReading = { 20, NULL };
      process_a_reading(&myReading);
}
```

Comment: @WeatherVane That makes no sense. Why would you upvote an answer that is wrong.

Comment: That was an error in the post, but my print statement still does not print anything.

Comment: Okay, now why would you pass a pointer? “Personally” isn’t a justification.

Comment: @1sand0s Honestly you should delete the answer, you don't address the problem, and the question should be closed since there is no problem presented.

Comment: @2501 - I'll let my answer stand because I like it :-) But I don't mind if you delete the question. I don't have the authority to just off and delete it myself.

Comment: @1sand0s That is not true. You can always delete your own answers.

Comment: @2501 I can but I don't want to delete my answer.  I don't mind if the question along with my answer is deleted. But if the question stands, I'd like my answer to as well.

Comment: @2501 because this answer was correct before the question was modified in response to the original answer, which too was edited.

Comment: @ZacharyStauffer If the answer helps you, please up vote it. If it resolves your issue, please click the grey √ beside it as well.